# Existence of non-zero scalars s.t. $\sum_{i=0}^{n^2}\alpha_i A^i=\mathcal{O}_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem to which I have not been able to find an answer given the theory so far covered in my linear algebra course:
Given a matrix $A\in$Mat$_{n,n}(\mathbb{F})$ (square matrix, $\mathbb{F}$ is any field), show that there exist $\alpha_o,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n^2}\in\mathbb{F}$ not all zero such that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n^2}\alpha_i A^i=\mathcal{O}_n
$$
where $\mathcal{O}_n$ is the zero matrix and $A^0$ is the identity matrix $\mathcal{I}_n$. 
The theory covered thus far is: inverse matrices, linear operators, linear (in)dependence, bases and dimension, but no dimension formulae have been proved yet.

Comment: The dimension of $M_{n\times n}$ is $n^2$ and there are $n^2+1$ elements in the list $I,A,A^2,...,A^{n^2}$.

Comment: There is also the Cayley Hamilton theorem.

Comment: @Tom, I do not see how that solves the problem?
We have not covered eigenvalues nor determinants, so I do not know how to use the Cayley Hamilton theorem.

Comment: The dimension of $M_{n\times n}$ is $n^2$. You can see this, for example, by checking that the $n^2$ matrices consisting of only zeros but one component which is one. You know that the size of any base is the dimension. You also know that any collection of vectors with more elements than the dimension ought to be linearly dependent. The collection $I,A,...,A^{n^2}$ has $n^2+1$ elements. Therefore it is linearly dependent. The definition of linearly dependent is that there exist $\alpha_i$, not all zero, such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n^2}\alpha_i A^i=\mathcal{O}$.